# A question about BMO

Tags: harmonic-analysis

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, suppose $f \in \mathrm{BMO}$ and $\phi \in \mathrm{C}_0^\infty$, then can we show that the convolution $f * \phi \in \mathrm{BMO}$?

Comment: Yes, we can. See for example: Harmonic Analysis by Stein. Chapter 4, section 4.